# Proof of "if $x<y$, then $xz<yz$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-writing, peano-axioms

I need help proving "For each $x,y,z$ in $\mathbb{N}$, if $x<y$, then $xz<yz$."

This must be done using Peano's axioms and the definitions of addition, multiplication, and ordering.

I have tried induction on z, and the base case works out but I run into an issue when it comes to the inductive part seeing as I am no longer dealing with equality.

Maybe induction is not the correct approach to this proof, and maybe a direct $P\implies Q$ proof would be more logical, however once I assume $x<y$, I don't have much to work with to deduce $xz<yz$, besides the definition of order.

Comment: Would it help if you rewrite $x < y$ as $\exists z > 0 : x+z = y$?

Comment: It is better to add the continuation to the original question instead of making it a comment.

Comment: Oops, just duplicated Hetebrij's comment.

Comment: I've tried to rewrite x<y in that form, but that doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is $x<y$. Then $x+m=y$ where $m>0$.

Then assume $xk<yk$. Then $xk+n=yk$ and $n>0$.

Then $xk+x+m+n=y+yk$

or $x(k+1)+(m+n)=y(k+1)$

Thus $x(k+1)<y(k+1)$.

Thus $xz<yz$ for all $z\in\Bbb{N}$.