# Show that $ xz \leq yz $ $ \land$ $ z > 0 $ $ \implies x \leq y $

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} $ Show that $ xz \leq yz  $ $ \land$ $ z > 0 $ $ \implies  x \leq y $.

Prove:

$ xz \leq yz  $ $ \implies 0 \leq yz -xz  \implies 0 \leq (y-x)\cdot z$

(For the next step, i want to use an axiom of the real numbers: for all $a,b  \in \mathbb{R} $  follows that $ 0 \leq a $ $\land$ $0 \leq b$ $\implies$ $0 \leq a\cdot b$.)

So by condition  $ z > 0 $ but i also must show that $0 \leq (y-x)$ how can i do these ?

Comment: $xz\leq yz\implies 0\leq yz-xz\implies 0\leq (y-x)z$.  This is where you stopped.  We know that the product of a negative number with a positive number will be negative.  If we were to assume that $(y-x)<0$ we would arrive at a contradiction as we would have had $(y-x)z$ simultaneously non-negative and negative, implying that $(y-x)$ cannot be negative.  This implies that $0\leq (y-x)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Cannot we just divide both sides of the starting inequality ($xz \leq yz$) with $z$, and since $z > 0$ get $x \leq y$ right away?

Comment: @bertalanp99 that depends on whether or not division has actually been defined at that point in the course.  This particular property is true and should be proven for the ring of integers as well far before the rational numbers are ever introduced and before the concept of division is ever formalized.

Comment: It is true as well for the natural numbers.  One can prove this for natural numbers even without the use of subtraction as that hasn't been defined yet at that point.  [See this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513546/proof-of-if-xy-then-xzyz?rq=1).